# java download from url directory

Tags: java, string, url, web-scraping, download

I need to develop some code that can detect any external links or directories, enter that directory then download whats inside that directory.
I'm working with a service that publishes a new file in a new directory (directory is named after the time-stamp it was created, name of the file is consistent though) and I need my code to download from that directory.

So far I've found some code and modified it to list the directories within the URL supplied, but how do I modify the code to enter the specific directory and download the particular file?

```
package list.links;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.helper.Validate;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ListLinks {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String URL = "insert url";

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
        Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");

        print("Links: (%d)", links.size());
        for (Element link : links) {
            //print(" * a: <%s>  (%s)", link.attr("abs:href"), trim(link.text(), 35));
            print(link.attr("abs:href"), trim(link.text(), 35));
        }
    }

    private static void print(String msg, Object... args) {
        System.out.println(String.format(msg, args));
    }

    private static String trim(String s, int width) {
        if (s.length() > width)
            return s.substring(0, width-1) + ".";
        else
            return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's seem that you want to using Jsoup to get a link, in that link have a folder and you want to go to that folder to download all files inside it. You can only access to a folder and download file via an `ftp` protocol. It's mean that you must have all the information of the server (server ip, username, pass)

Comment: Thats right, its a folder with an item I need to download, problem is the directory will keep changing, how do I use ftp via java (I have to google java file transfer protocol?)

Comment: [for your refer](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/ftp/java-ftp-file-download-tutorial-and-example)

Comment: ok im working on that atm but in the meanwhile at the 'print(link.attr("abs:href"), trim(link.text(), 35));' line, the code is returning a several links that are not relevant to me, what is an efficient way to extract the directory I need? i.e. the directory will contain 2017 because the directory is named after its timestamp but it seems I can't treat 'link' the same as a string

Comment: In the for loop, you have `Element` you can use [`element.getAttribute('href')`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/index.html) this will return a `String` => check if this string is contain 2017 or not